# Read window's registry in QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to list all application which had been installed by reading uninstall registry file from HKEY_CURRENT_USER. But look like it can't be done by using QSettings, for some security reason ( i guess ).

```
QSettings maya("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall
```

People suggest to use WinAPI to accomplish this (at least, on Window platform)

Can somebody guide me how to add and use this lib please?
Thank

Comment: The Win32 API is already linked by Qt, so all you'd have to do to use it is #include <windows.h>

Comment: Hi MrEricSir
Do you have any example of query application using win32_product?

Comment: If you mean win32, I'm sure you can find plenty examples here on SO.

Answer (score 17):

In order to get the list of all sub items under the "Uninstall" one in the Windows registry you need to use `QSettings::childGroups()` function, i.e:

```
QSettings m("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall",
            QSettings::NativeFormat);
QStringList ak = m.childGroups();
```

This will return the list of all installed applications.

**UPDATE:**

After getting the list of installed applications one can read the installation details. There are two ways for doing that. For example to read the "UinstallPath" key for "Autodesk Maya 2014" application:

```
m.beginGroup("Autodesk Maya 2014");
QString path = m.value("UninstallPath").toString();
m.endGroup();
```

or simply:

```
QString path = m.value("Autodesk Maya 2014/UninstallPath").toString();
```

Comment: Can i get the key, value from it too?

Comment: @illunara, key or value or both? Get it from what? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Sorry for an unclear question, let's say i want to get the path to application. Normally, i can use QSettings().value("key"), but for win7 x64 it always return "" empty

Comment: @illunara, where the path to application stored? Do you mean "UninstallString" value? Can you give an example?

Comment: I attached part of registry export data here
https://gist.github.com/illunara/6c16ec23b726d54e6e82
For example Autodesk Maya 2014, i want to get value from "UninstallPath"
is "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\Setup\\Setup.exe".

Oh and btw, i follow the way you told me earlier, but not all application in the Uninstall was listed O_O

Comment: Sorry, vahancho. No luck, i attached a thumbnail here so you can see the output.
http://postimg.org/image/ystv96cj3/

It works well under [HKEY_CURRENT_USER] through. I'm using Win 7 x64 btw.