# Get Full Path Default Browser in Qt (Windows Linux Mac)

Tags: qt, path

title is exhaustive. I don't know how to use function like `QDesktopService` or get the data from registry ( is this possible solution sustainable? )

**Edit**:

With Reg its possible to retrieve default default browser

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. What exactly do you need to do with `QDesktopService`? To read the registry you could use [QSettings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795410/read-windows-registry-in-qt).

Comment: This info might also help you: [Getting Default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733211/getting-default-browser) - at least for windows.

Comment: thanks for your answer Dusteh i have finally cracked how to use QDesktopServices to get the path of default browser in use with qt

Comment: I just found how to extract value from registry with qt and then i used the method to extract the default browser from the key registry where he is stored

Comment: In such case you should answer your own question as described here: [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)